# $this->myObject = clone $this->myObject;

Tags: php, oop

I have a question regarding object cloning in PHP. I understand that clone creates a "deep copy" in that a new object is created with its variables initialized to the values of the corresponding variables in the object from which it is cloned. However, [as discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809439/php-clone-and-the-shallow-clone), this means that any reference variables will be references to the same value, likely creating issues.

The book I'm reading gives the following solution, similar to the one given at the above link:

```
class ReferenceClass {
  public $msg = 'Reference Object';
}

class CloneClass {
  public $refObj;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->refObj = new ReferenceClass();
  }

  public function __clone() {
    $this->refObj = clone $this->$refObj;
  }
}
```

However, try as I might, I can't wrap my head around what's happening with this line:

```
    $this->refObj = clone $this->$refObj;
```

Any light anyone may be able to shed will be a huge help.

Comment: Not sure if this may or not help you, but in the official PHPOOP5 documentation there is an example **very** similar to your case: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php . check example #1

Comment: It looks like it is saying "when making a deep copy, make a deep copy of the reference object member". The simplest hack to get true deep copies (I think) is `unserialize(serialize($obj))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question.

The line that you've pointed out is cloning the referenced objects, therefore avoiding double-pointer issues.

Hence, the `_clone` method does not only clone the object itself, but also all it's referenced objects.

For example, if you had a car object of id 1 which had a reference to an engine object of id 1, after the clone you will have a new car identified by 2 and a new engine identified by 2.
Without the `_clone` extension, you would have had a car identified by 2 referencing an engine identified by 1.

Please note, magic clone is only required for objects with non-primitive types as attributes.

Comment: In cloning the referenced object using clone, wouldn't you encounter the same problem again if the referenced object also had reference variables in it?

Comment: Yes, which is why you should implement this method in all your relevant objects (object which have non-primitive types as attributes.)

Comment: Okay, so in the example above, no __clone magic method is needed in ReferenceClass since ReferenceClass's only variable is primitive. Is this understanding correct? ADDITION: does this also mean that the __construct method is not used when cloning?

Comment: Wait, Am I the only one unable to clone the object? it throws a fatal error, and it has his sense.

Comment: I should make this a separate comment rather than an addition to avoid confusion: is it correct to think of __clone() as a "stand in" for __construct which is used rather than __construct at the time of cloning?

Comment: Somewhat correct - don't forget that the source object has already gone through _construct at the time of creation, therefore guaranteeing validity of certain fields etc. It is the hook with which you reset fields that should be unique for each object, and clone the ones who you do not want referenced.

Comment: Got it, thanks again. This cleared things up for me.